# Removing only captured group using grep

Tags: url, command-line, grep

I have a list of urls, all of them look like `http://example.com/page?id=1234`

How can I use grep (or any tool) to remove everything that is after `=`

Like, the above should like this `http://example.com/page?id=` after running the command.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: OK. The command I can think of is `grep -oP "(https|http)://.*=" urls.txt` - but I was wondering if there's a new way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed and its `s` command:

```
sed 's/=[^=]*$/=/' file
```

or GNU grep and Perl-compatible regular expressions:

```
grep -Po '.*=(?=.*)' file
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/page?id=
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)